# Access to files on Windows 2003 server from Mac

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac

I can access the Windows 2003 server from my Mac, but can't see all the files. I am using Snow Leopard and have followed fixes online. All get me connected and I can see all folders, but not all files within these folders appear.

Someone else using a Mac can see all files which is very odd.

Any help much appreciated.

C

Comment: How are you connecting to the Windows box? Using SMB just works and requires no fixes, so I'm guessing you're using something else.

Comment: Using SMB. I can access the server, see the folders, but only see files in a few of the folders

Comment: If you go to a Windows client and log into the server using *your* account, can you see those files?

Comment: Very strange. Overnight, the problem seems to have resolved itself. Don't know how, but will try to find out. I could see all the files using a Windows Client. Many thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have permissions to view these files? Ask your systems administrator to check this for you.

Comment: I have access to all the folders. All of the folders have files n them, but I can only see files in about 70% of them.